# How can i use @DiscriminatorColumn in the equals method of the entity?

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, orm

Actually the Question is in the title.

The entities will be map Comments for different objects in system(Blog nodes, comments, etc.)
so I want to be able work with this column(read it's value for building comment tree for particular type of Commented object type.
Also I want to add `@DiscriminatorColumn` in the `equals` and `hashcode` methods.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem comes as whenever you load the entity, the discriminator value is always null. So  if you try to add the discriminator value in equals you might get null pointer, So to do so there are two ways:-

1. One is whenever you use discriminator, you have certain sub classes, then on the basis of sub classes you can equate two objects.
2. You can add a sort of temporary variable in your entity, and then while mapping you can `insert="false" update="false"` on to that attribute, which will make your attribute read only, and then for that attribute you can put the equals.

eg:-

```
private String tempDiscriminatorValue;
<property name="tempDiscriminatorValue" type="string" column="DISCR_VAL" insert="false" update="false"/>
```

Comment: thanks for responce, but i think, it would be easier to manually add type field and not use inheritance. It seems that my case isn't the best way for using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

DiscriminatorColumns are for inheritance, an instance of class A is implicitly not equal to a class B, so I do not understand why you would do this??

equals() would normally do a,

```
if (object instanceof Foo) {
  return ...
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: i need to check the logical equivelence (Comment with type BlogComment and text X equals Comment with Type BlogComment and text X)